# Xamarin.Forms: Android picture renderer is basically useless

Tags: xamarin.forms

So, I am trying to achieve the effect as shown in this picture (regarding the party picture)

[image]

This is a snap shot from the iOS version of the app simply following this code:

```
<Image Source="{Binding picture}"/>
```

So, as you see, all thats needed to show this picture like this is one line of code (on iOS at least).

Cause this is what that will look like on Android:

[image]

So, youll see, it renderes it way too tiny, just inside a corner.

To get to (almost) the same results as on the iOS version, I have to alter the code like this:

```
           <Image Source="{Binding picture}"
                  VerticalOptions="Start"
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                  HeightRequest="171"/>
```

Giving it height values and so much more stuff, and in the end it still shows slight borders (about a pixel wide) and this is just a terrible solution.

What is the best way of showing the party image just the same as it is on the iOS version just on Android?

Why is Droid rendering the image tiner, not taking up all the space as iOS does?

Comment: Remove your `HeightRequest` and set `Aspect` property to `AspectFill`

Comment: this clips the picture in half but fills the parent in width

Answer (score 0):

There is an Aspect attribute inside Image. According to the official document, the default value of the Aspect attribute is AspectFit. You can auto-fill by setting the Aspect property to AspectFill. Here is the official document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.aspect?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: this fill the width, but the picture is only redered half. so half is just clipped. (ios works fine)

Comment: Try to use "fill"